# suggestion for lyapunov function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations

> Consider differential equation \begin{align}x'&=-t(x+y)\\ y'&=-y+x-y(y^2-6).\end{align} Can some one suggest a lyapunov function for it.

I have examined $V(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ , $V(x,y)=(1+t^2)(x^2+y^2)$ , $V(x,y)=(1+t^2)^2(x^2+y^2)$ but I could not solve the stablity with these functions.

Thanks

Comment: Are you assuming $(0,0)$ is a stable solution? I ran a few sample solutions at fixed values of $t$, and it looks like the stable solutions are $(-2,2)$ and $(2,-2)$, not $(0,0)$.

Comment: Yes for $(0,0)$

Comment: As far as I remember, there's a kind of general recommendation. If equilibrium is hyperbolic and you know a Lyapunov function for its linearization, then the same Lyapunov function would work for non-linear system at least in a small neighbourhood of this equilibrim.